# Load 60 images in stackpanel or Listbox from folder in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I load 60 images in stackpanel  or Listbox from folder in windows phone 8 (C# and Xaml) and when I Click specific button I'll load another images from another folder?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far..

Comment: I need something like that but replace string to images and load it in listbox in Xaml load it from folder in solution
--------------------------------------
 string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Garrith-Super-PC\Desktop\New folder");
13
 
14
    foreach (string file in files)
15
    {
16
 
17
        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
18
 
19
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code i used to list images,

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}" 
        MinHeight="100">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="50" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here, ImageCollection is

```
public static IEnumerable<Uri> ImageCollection { get; set; }
```

which will contain you image Uri's

hope this helps

Comment: thank U very much but now i have new Problem that memory leak because there are a lot of images in listbox .. what should i do ?